# Search words in line of an external file in c++

Tags: c++, file

I have the following problem:
I have a text file `file.txt` which contains several lines in which I want to search for specific words. The words I want to search for are in a second file `input.txt`, which may look like this:

```
Paul
Matt
Joseph
```

In the first loop I want to search for Paul, in the second for Matt and in the third for Joseph. Each time I find the specific name in a line of the text file, I want to output the line and keep on searching through all following lines of the text file.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
ifstream fs("input.txt");
ifstream stream1("file.txt");
ofstream stream2("output.txt");
string Name;
string line;


while (fs >> Name)
{
    while (std::getline(stream1, line))
    {
        if ((line.find(Name) != string::npos))

        {
            stream2 << Name << line << endl;
        }
        else
            stream2 << "Unable to find name in line" << endl;;
    }   
}


fs.close();
stream1.close();
stream2.close();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The problem with my code is that it searches for the first word fine, but it stops after the `first loop`. It does not search for the second word `("e.g. Matt").`

Maybe someone has an idea what I have made for a mistake.

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Because you never _seek_ back to the beginning of the file after the first search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `open` `input.txt` then read all elements from this file when `name = Paul`. After read all, `cursor` will be stand at the end of file `input.txt`. That's why, when you again search for Matt, You can't find anything.

So, you should always start search from the `input.txt`. So, you can do that for open this file then cursor will be stand first.

Just simple change:

```
while (fs >> Name)
{
    ifstream stream1("file.txt");
    while (std::getline(stream1, line))
    {
        if ((line.find(Name) != string::npos))

        {
            stream2 << Name << line << endl;
        }
        else
            stream2 << "Unable to find name in line" << endl;;
    }
    stream1.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the inner loop is done, you're at the end of the file for `stream1`. You need to "rewind" the read position to the beginning. This can be done by [*seeking*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) to the first position.